# How to get the same result as modifying /etc/hosts file, without root access?

Tags: hosts, domain-name-system

The question is simple: no root access, but need to point particular domain name to the specified IP address.

What are the other ways to do the same thing as with adding the record to /etc/hosts file?

UPDATE:

Clarification:
My domain had been expired, but I still want to gain the access to it from corporate network (no root privileges on my linux workstation) by it's domain name for: http, https, imaps, smtps, ftp, and couple of specific ports.

Comment: for what software do you require this?

Comment: Why not discuss this with your system administrator?

Comment: I'm the one of a few tens thousands of employees in our corporation, and this problem is a personal issue.

Answer (score 5):

You could [LD_PRELOAD](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7795) in your own versions of gethostby{addr,name..} 
which read /etc/hosts and then the users own hosts file in their homedirectory.

Comment: +1 Have to remember this for the next time April 1st rolls around :-)

Answer (score 0):

The server is using a nameserver right ? (`cat /etc/resolv.conf`) so you could, if you have access, configure it to return a specific IP address for a particular domain.

Comment: If he had root access to change /etc/resolv.conf, then he could change /etc/hosts too.